# What is the equivalent of spring's @ComponentScan on the CDI Java EE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cdi, java-ee-8

Today, in Spring boot I do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = ["br.com.gubee"],
    includeFilters = [ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = [UseCase::class])])
class DomainConfiguration
```

The annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface UseCase
```

Defining my bean:

```
 @UseCase
  class Test
```

Comment: Hello! If I read your example correctly, you are telling Spring to consider as beans classes under the `br.com.gubee` package (and subpackages?) annotated with `@UseCase`. Is this exactly what you are trying to do? Or is it just an example and you are actually looking for general guidance on how to tell CDI what classes to consider as beans? (Or something else?)

Comment: Don't do that. Don't do "Spring VS JEE" comparisons, even though they solve conceptually the same problems they do so in very different ways. You have something you want to achieve using CDI - ask about that (but first of all: research that). Don't ask how to translate something in Spring to something else.